# php curl timeout request but entries are inserted into DB

Tags: php, api, curl, request

i have question. 
i write a api connect to insert data into the database.

even when i try this over "Postman" all works fine.

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => "https://dev.daypaio.com/api/transaction?access_token=here are the accesstoken",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\n  \"transactionID\": \"98892374982739847\",\n  \"note\": \"hier ist eine note\",\n  \"referer\": \"http://www.google.de\",\n  \"createOrder\": true,\n  \"coupon\": \"coupon2018\",\n  \"newsletter\": true,\n  \"billingAdress\": {\n    \"email\": \"is@daniel-mauer.de\",\n    \"phone\": \"3243245345\",\n    \"cell\": \"435654645645\",\n    \"ext_id\": 0,\n    \"first_name\": \"Inge\",\n    \"last_name\": \"Sockenschuss\",\n    \"street\": \"Sockenstreet 123\",\n    \"zip\": \"12345\",\n    \"city\": \"Sockenhausen\",\n    \"country\": \"Germany\",\n    \"dob\": \"1980-12-12\",\n    \"demographic\": {\n      \"gender\": \"female\",\n      \"job\": \"Socken CEO\",\n      \"nationality\": \"german\",\n      \"disability\": \"none\"\n    }\n  },\n  \"attributes\": [\n    {\n      \"name\": \"\",\n      \"value\": \"\"\n    }\n    \n  ],\n  \"aattributes\": [\n    {\n      \"name\": \"\",\n      \"value\": \"\"\n    }\n  ],\n  \"connections\": [\n    {\n      \"kind\": \"\",\n      \"t\": \"contact\",\n      \"tags\": [\n        \"...\",\"...\"\n      ],\n      \"email\": \"\",\n      \"phone\": \"\",\n      \"cell\": \"\",\n      \"first_name\": \"\",\n      \"last_name\": \"\"\n    }\n  ],\n  \"products\": [\n    {\n      \"pos\": 1,\n      \"name\": \"\",\n      \"tax\": 0,\n      \"price\": 0,\n      \"desc\": \"\",\n      \"category\": \"\",\n      \"unit\": \"\",\n      \"qty\": 1,\n      \"typ\": \"\",\n      \"brand\": \"\",\n      \"start\": \"\",\n      \"end\": \"\",\n      \"duration\": 1,\n      \"durationUnit\": \"days\",\n      \"sku\": \"\"\n    }\n  ],\n  \"total\": 0,\n  \"sum\": 0\n}",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"cache-control: no-cache",
"content-type: application/json",
"postman-token: def0a6ec-96b4-7983-a32b-2431fddf7812"
   ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

This is the code from Postman that works. 
but when i try to create it dynamicly into php the curl request becomes an timeout an insert the entries into the database.

here the php code:

```
    $json_array = array(
        'transactionID'     => time().mt_rand(),
        'note'              => 'hier kommen notes hinein',
        'referer'           => $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],
        'createOrder'       => true,
        'coupon'            => generateCouponCode(),
        'newsletter'        => true,
        'billingAddress'    => array(
            'email'             => 'email@daniel-mauer.de',
            'phone'             => '1234567890',
            'cell'              => '123456756867',
            'ext_id'            => mt_rand(),
            'first_name'        => 'Daniel',
            'last_name'         => 'Mauer',
            'street'            => 'Am Tierpark 8',
            'zip'               => '98527',
            'city'              => 'Suhl',
            'country'           => 'Deutschland',
            'dob'               => '1985-11-01',
            'demographic'       => array(
                'gender'            => 'male',
                'job'               => 'Developer',
                'nationality'       => 'deutsch',
                'disability'        => 'none'
            ),
            'danielField'       => 'daniel sein feld'
        ),
    );


    $json_array_short = array(
        'transactionID'     => time().mt_rand(),
        'note'              => 'hier kommen notes hinein',
        'referer'           => $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],
        'createOrder'       => true,
        'coupon'            => generateCouponCode()
    );

    $jsonObject = json_encode($json_array);
    $jsonObjectShort = json_encode($json_array_short);





    $curl = curl_init();
    //print_r($curl);

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://dev.daypaio.com/api/transaction?access_token=token comes here",
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $jsonObjectShort,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Content-Type: application/json"
        ),
    ));
    //print_r('<br /><br />' . $curl);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    print_r($response . '<br /><br />');
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);


    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        echo $response;
    }

    if(!curl_exec($curl)){
        die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
    }
```

Comment: well, you may have a missing `curl_setopt($url , CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION , 1);`.  When in doubt, there are the obvious priceless tools `curl_getinfo($curl)` , as well as `CURLOPT_VERBOSE`.

Comment: and oups ... the elephant in the room, this is https. Plenty of examples here to fix your request.